# Can I use Overlays in Profile in maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Can I use **overlays** in **profile**?

I have to build and package my web app such as it has to copy the resources from another project only for specified profile. So How can I achieve this, please suggest some solution.

Comment: Linked to question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385245/how-to-use-maven-profile-and-overlays-to-build-and-package-with-specified-projec/24401254#24401254

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not use Overlays in Profile, but we can achieve this as shown here [Use **Overlay** with **Profile**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385245/how-to-use-maven-profile-and-overlays-to-build-and-package-with-specified-projec/24401254#24401254)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what kind of project you're copying from.

If it's a WAR project, then depending on it will cause maven to overlay the resources automatically. So, all you need to do is have a `dependencies` section in your profile, and within that add a dependency on your other WAR, and maven will overlay it for you.

If it's a jar project, you can zip up your resources using the assembly plugin, and unzip into your war using the dependencies:unpack plugin. I probably can't do better than the accepted answers on these two questions:

- [Creating a zip archive of the maven "target" directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514429/creating-a-zip-archive-of-the-maven-target-directory) for how to create the zip of your resources.
- [Unzip dependency in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388661/unzip-dependency-in-maven)
  for how to unzip into your war.

Update: as an alternative to unpacking the zip, you can use the overlays part of the WAR plugin, see the last example on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

Comment: Yes it is a JAR project, Can you please elaborate more on the second part of you answer? Sorry but I am new to maven.

Comment: See updated answer - the two links give good example of the two parts of the process.

Comment: thanks stripybadger for you support...Its really useful :)

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you can run it on com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer. because JAX-RS is a specification which have been implemented by various vendors like, Apche,jersey,jboss,spring  etc. They provide there own server to run the web services which fulfill the desired criteria.
Although restful web services runs over http but as per me they can't run on com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.
Hope it will help you